# Regarding Vector Memory Storage

Tags: c++, vector

I am learning how vectors work in c++, and wrote a sample program to try to learn how memory with vectors are handled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

//Test 1:
double n = 3.5;
std::vector<double> test;
std::cout <<  sizeof(test) << std::endl;
test.push_back(n);    
std::cout << sizeof(test) << std::endl;

std::cout << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::endl;

//Test 2


std::vector<int> test2;
std::cout << sizeof(test2) << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

 test2.push_back(i);   

}

 std::cout << sizeof(test2) << std::endl;
}
```

Interestingly, the program prints out 24 as the number of bytes stored each-time. Despite adding new elements to the vector. How is the amount of memory that the vector occupies when it is initially declared the same as after I have added elements to the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, the `vector` object has a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory that contains the elements. When you use `sizeof(test)` you're just getting the size of the structure that contains the pointer, the size of the memory that it points to is not included.

This memory has to be dynamically-allocated so that the vector can grow and shrink as needed. It's not possible for a class object to change its size.

To get the amount of memory being used by the data storage, use `sizeof(double) * test.capacity()`.